# GCP: Invalid resource usage: 'UEFI feature is not available for this project.'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, uefi

I created an image using the `--guest-os-features="UEFI_COMPATIBLE"` option as described [in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#guest-os-features) but when trying to instantiate an VM Instance (using the Console and gcloud) I get the following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch
>   resource:
>
> - Invalid resource usage: 'UEFI feature is not available for this project.'

I also tried `beta compute images create` and `beta compute instances create` without success.

I understand that there must be a way to enable the UEFI feature for my project but searching through all the documentation, stackoverflow and google the only relevant information I could find does not cover how to enable this feature:

- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#guest-os-features
- https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/create#guestOsFeatures

I searched all the Quotas, API's, Permissions, Management and also tried `"SECURE_BOOT"` and `"SECURE_BOOT,UEFI_COMPATIBLE"` all with the same error.

And no, the problem is not with my disk image as the problem occurs before booting. It can also be very easily replicated using an empty image:

```sh
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=100 of=disk.raw
tar -Sczf disk.tar.gz disk.raw

gsutil cp disk.tar.gz gs://...
gcloud compute images create [name] --guest-os-features="UEFI_COMPATIBLE" \
    --source-uri=gs://...
gcloud compute instances create [inst-name] --image=[name] ...
```

*Note: I originally posted this to stackoverflow because I didn't realize it would fit here better. So if this gets flagged for repost or spam, I deleted the original.*

Comment: What is the actual question you want answered?

Comment: @womble How do I enable this feature? Why is the documentation nowhere stating how and why this feature is disabled? Can I manually enable this feature somewhere? Do I have to ask the support? Why do only this question and the documentation come up when googling _google cloud "UEFI_COMPATIBLE"_? Am I the only person with this problem? Did nobody ever try this? Basically, I wanted to try this feature because I found it in the documentation but can't find any evidence that this has ever worked and is not just a stub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know when they fixed it but as of 21. August 2019 everything is working as expected and the error is gone.